# What is the Physical Significance of The Coefficients of Angular Momentum Ladder Operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, dimensional-analysis

For example, in a spin 1 system in a state $|-1\rangle$, lets raise it twice, and the state becomes $2\hbar^2|+1\rangle$, now lets lower it twice, we get $4\hbar^4|-1\rangle$. Keep going and the $\hbar$ factors keep piling on. What is the physical significance of this factor? Why don't we get back to $|-1\rangle$?

Answer (score 2):

The angular momentum operators have units of $\hbar$ so their action contains $\hbar$; these accumulate just in the same way that $E_n$ accumulates when you write 
\begin{align}
\hat H\vert n\rangle &=E_n\vert n\rangle\, ,\\
(\hat H)^k\vert n\rangle &=(E_n)^k\vert n\rangle\, .
\end{align}

The angular version would be
$$
\hat L_z\vert \ell,m\rangle=m\hbar \vert \ell,m\rangle\, ,
\quad (\hat L_z)^k\vert \ell,m\rangle=(m\hbar)^k \vert \ell,m\rangle.
$$

Such repeated actions of operators are useful in generating finite transformation, such as the time evolution 
$$
U(t)=e^{-i t \hat H/\hbar}= 1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
\frac{1}{k!}\left(\frac{-i t\hat H}{\hbar}\right)^k
$$
or a finite rotation
$$
R_z(\theta)=e^{-i\theta \hat L_z/\hbar}=1+
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k!} 
\left(\frac{-i \theta\hat L_z}{\hbar}\right)^k\, .
$$

Comment: +1 Although it should be pointed out that the spin states the OP refers to are not eigenstates of the raising or lowering operators, so your example is not exactly the same.

Comment: @AaronStevens right but the action of an dimensionful operator still needs to carry the correct dimensionful factor, whether the states are eigenstates or not.

Comment: I understand and agree. It just took me a second to realize which part of the example applied here and which did not. I thought a comment might help someone who would also be confused but not be able to figure it out.

Comment: @AaronStevens Thank you for the answer, that makes sense from a dimensional standpoint, but I'd like to ask what is the physical interpretation of applying the hamiltonian operator repeatedly? Is there one? I think I'm just conceptually all wrong. Would these factors just get wiped out when renormalized, so it doesn't effect the value of a future measurement?

Comment: @walczyk added a bit to answer your query.

Comment: @walczyk This isn't my answer :)

Comment: @AaronStevens yeah for your sake you don't want anyone to think you're me... or *vice versa*...

Comment: I wouldn't mind being a hero :)

Answer (score 1):

There is some flexibility in how one can define these operators. Ladder operators don't need to carry these constants. For instance, for the number states, one can define the ladder operator such that they simply give
$$ a^{\dagger} |n\rangle = |n+1\rangle \sqrt{1+n} , \\ a |n\rangle = |n-1\rangle \sqrt{n} . $$
The same applies for spin operators. Often one can get rid of the Planck constant through normalization.

It is a good idea to remove the Planck constant as far as possible to avoid some confusion the comes with the association between the Planck constant and quantum effects.

For instance, there does not need to be a Planck in the commutation relations of spin operators. The reason is that these spin operators are just the generators for rotation, which is not intrinsically a quantum process.

The situations where one cannot get rid of the Planck constant are those situations that involve interactions. These are situations that represent intrinsic quantum effects.